# openURL for some phone numbers is failing

Tags: ios, iphone, uiapplication, openurl

I'm trying to make a call programmatically to a number which has double extension.

When I try to run this,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:2133776478,213#,213#"]]]
```

I get "No" as the response. But when I type this number on WhatsApp, I'm allowed to make a call with this number.

Is there a better to achieve this? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html),

`To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.`

I would try using the escaped version of the telephone number first (using `NSString:stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`), and if that fails, I would try removing the `,` and `#` characters.

Answer (score 0):

A tel: URL with a single # works, but the presence of two # characters is  an invalid URL as far as `NSURL` is concerned because it looks like the URL contains two anchor segments.  This results in a `nil` NSURL.

If you percent-encode your string then the # characters simply become part of the URL string and it all works:

```
NSString *baseString = @"tel:2133776478,213#,213#";
NSString *encodedString = [baseString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (encodedString != nil) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
    if (url != nil) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```